# C# Передача параметра подмодулям

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, properties, observer

Всем доброго дня).

Ситуация: Двигатель (Engine) имеет свойство модель (Model).

Есть иерархия: Двигатель (Engine) -> Все Параметры (AllParams) -> Параметры (Param1, Param2, Param3 и т. д.).

Каждый Param представляет собой объект заданного класса (Param1, Param2, Param3 и т.д.). В каждом Param есть свойство Model, которое описывает объект класса Engine, в котором эти параметры и находятся.

В крайне упрощенном виде код данной ситуации представлен внизу:

```
public class Engine {
    public EngineModel Model {get; private set;}

    public AllParams allParams;

    public Engine(EngineModel Model) {
        this.Model = Model;
        allParams = new AllParams();
}

public void UpdateModel(EngineModel newModel) {
        Model = newModel;
    }
}

public class EngineModel {
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}

public class AllParams {
    public Param1 param1;
    public Param2 param2;
    public Param3 param3;

    public AllParams() {
        param1 = new Param1();
        param2 = new Param2();
        param3 = new Param3();      
    }   
}

public class Param1 {
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}

public class Param2 {
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}

public class Param3 {
    public string ModelName {get; set;}
}
```

С точки зрения архитектурного проектирования, как лучше организовать изменение Model в каждом Param при изменении модели двигателя?

У меня есть две идеи:

1) В классе AllParams организовать метод UpdateModel, который изменит значение Model в каждом из Param, входящих в AllParams.

2) В классе AllParams определить класс ModelObservable для хранения Model и вызова события ModelChanged. В свою очередь, каждый Param подписывается на событие ModelChanged и получает измененное значение Model

Или 1 и 2 вариант полная чушь и надо сделать совсем по-другому?

Comment: Не понятно с этими `Param1..2..3` они чем-нибудь будут отличаться друг от друга? Может для них сделать один базовый класс?

Comment: Все Param могут отличаться друг от друга в некоторой степени. В своем вопросе я привел упрощенный пример. Общим на данный момент у них является свойство ModelName.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не стой стороны к проектированию заходите. Нужно прежде всего рассмотреть предметную часть из реального физического мира, какие объекты, какие у них свойства, какие между ними возникают связи, что общего между ними. Плясать нужно от печки, а не от абстрактных `Param`.

Comment: В данный момент описание в вопросе предметной области считаю излишним. Я описал ту иерархию, которая получается в конечном итоге. Замена названий Param1, Param2, Param3 на "Давление сжатия", "Давление горения" и т.д. только запутает. Связи уже определены. В своем посте я описал конкретный вопрос относительно обновления свойства у параметров).

Comment: Ну и ответ вы тогда получите такой же абстрактный и вероятнее всего в итоге неверный. Хотите воздушных замков? Ваше право...

Comment: Bulson, благодарю Вас за неравнодушие к моему вопросу, но все же повторюсь: иерархия в архитектуре уже определена. Можно изменить Param на любые другие названия. Суть не изменится: параметр есть параметр. В данном случае вопрос в грамотном способе обновления свойства ModelName у параметров.

Comment: Простой вариант изменение двигателя вызывает событие у двигателя, он передает информацию в allparams, а дальше как хотите.

Comment: Вот честно, в текущем виде архитектура выглядит ужасно. Или конкретизируйте, что из себя представляют параметры, или не используйте отдельные классы там, где можно воспользоваться строковыми полями/свойствами. Например, у вашего двигателя есть свойство модель, у которой есть свойство `Name` - **и больше ничего нет**. Гораздо логичнее описать у двигателя свойство `string ModelName`. Опять же, неясно, что требуется от Парамов. Может быть, логичнее всего вообще формировать их "на лету" в геттере

Comment: Раз изменение `EngineModel` должно повлечь за собой изменения `Param1`, `Param2`, `Param3`, то наверное можно организовать логику изменения этих объектов в самом сеттере `EngineModel`.